# (NATIVESCRIPT) Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

We have checked our entire code base and found no reference to **UIWebView**, but every time we upload a new version to Apple we get the warning "**ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs**". Could any of you please guide us if we are missing out to look out at something.

**Below are the project dependencies that have been used**

```
        "@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/http": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
        "nativescript-angular": "~7.1.0",
        "nativescript-drop-down": "^4.0.1",
        "nativescript-ios-uuid": "^1.0.0",
        "nativescript-oauth2": "^1.4.1",
        "nativescript-phone": "^1.4.0",
        "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^8.1.1",
        "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
        "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^5.1.0",
        "nativescript-urlhandler": "^1.2.3",
        "nativescript-uuid": "0.0.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
        "rxjs": "~6.3.0",
        "tns-core-modules": "~5.1.0",
        "tns-platform-declarations": "^5.3.1",
        "typescript-tslint-plugin": "^0.3.1",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
```

Comment: {N} v3.4 and above already uses WKWebView. Is the same deprecation warning shown, even if you create a new project on your machine.

Comment: Yes we are using Nativescript version 5.1.0 and we still have the same issue.

Comment: When you say "still have the same issue", you have it on a brand new template created by CLI?

Comment: No its a template that was created in JAN 2019

Comment: I'm asking you to try a new template so at least you can figure out whether the issue is on the machine or just with your project. It's up to you if you want to debug that way, it will at least take you a step forward if it's only within project.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue due to a Nativescript plugin using an iOS library / Pod-file (AFNetworking https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/search?q=uiwebview&type=Issues), so I would suggest you go through the repos of your plugins, specifically

```
        "nativescript-drop-down": "^4.0.1",
        "nativescript-ios-uuid": "^1.0.0",
        "nativescript-oauth2": "^1.4.1",
        "nativescript-phone": "^1.4.0",
        "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^5.1.0",
        "nativescript-urlhandler": "^1.2.3",
        "nativescript-uuid": "0.0.1",
```

and check for references to `UIWebView` or the issue lists.